# How should I arrange a foreign word and its translation in middle of sentence?

Tags: american-english, spanish, foreign-phrases

I'm having trouble with this sentence:

> "I possess what in spanish we call *ganas*, the desire, to attain a graduate degree."

I think it's clear what I'm trying to say, but it sounds wrong. It feels like I'm saying *ganas* means "the desire to attain a gruduate degree" instead of just "the desire".

What is the correct way to write this?

Thanks!

Comment: With the commas it is unambiguous.

Comment: It's clearer with dashes: *I possess what in spanish we call ganas—the desire—to attain a graduate degree.*

Comment: *spanish* should be *Spanish*.

Comment: I wonder why you bother to include this text at all: "*what in spanish we call ganas*". The question is fine, but I wonder why you don't just say "*I would like to obtain a graduate degree*". Or if *ganas* is particularly strong, then "*I want very much to...*."

Comment: Yeah, we have a word in English for desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use parenthesis

> I possess what in spanish we call **ganas** (*a strong desire*) to attain a graduate degree.